# HTML5 content on android?

Tags: android, html

I want to show HTML5 content on android, but I don't know what are the content are support, and how we can display these?

can any one suggest me?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at a website called [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/). It allows you to look up elements and functionality and see an overview of browser support (including Android's browser).

Comment: Thanks, do u have any idea how to use HTML5 for android?

Comment: @Shubh In the same way as you would on any browser.

Comment: site which u suggest it really helpful...let me dig it more.

Answer (score 0):

Android browser supports HTML5 content..

and in android app

use webview to show HTML5 content..
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html